# Celery chain inside a chord argument error

Tags: python, task, celery

I'm trying to run a chain inside a chord in celery.
My workflow looks like this:

`task1.s(arg1) | task2.s() | chord([task3.s(), (task4a.s()| task4b.s())], task5.s()) | task 6.s()`

where :

- `task3` and `task4a` are taking same arguments (=return value of `task2`)
- `task5` should wait for both `task3` and `task4b` to finish (and take their output as input).

When running such a pipe, it seems that only `task3` received the output of `task2`as argument. Indeed I'm having an error of kind `TypeError: task4a() missing 1 required positional argument`.

If I replace the chain `(task4a.s()| task4b.s())` by a single task, there is no error and argument are well passed. It seems that celery does not handle chain in chords (or I don't know how to use it).

I do not want to "fuse" my 2 tasks into 1 (because I need to see intermediate results). Has anyone encounter a similar issue and find a solution/workaround?

Cheers

**Edit**: I use celery 4.1.0 with redis backend and RabbitMQ broker.

Comment: You might want to share your setup: celery version, broker, backend..